# ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cloudtrail

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
httplib_response = self._make_request(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 978, in *validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 362, in connect
self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 384, in ssl_wrap_socket
return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 254, in send
urllib_response = conn.urlopen(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 379, in increment
raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
httplib_response = self._make_request(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 978, in *validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 362, in connect
self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 384, in ssl_wrap_socket
return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/kbollu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/py-tests/aws-scripts/elevatedaccess-role-CT.py", line 6, in 
events = ct.lookup_events(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 357, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 662, in _make_api_call
http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 682, in _make_request
return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 136, in _send_request
while self._needs_retry(attempts, operation_model, request_dict,
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 253, in _needs_retry
responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 356, in emit
return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 228, in emit
return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
response = handler(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 183, in **call**
if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 250, in **call**
should_retry = self._should_retry(attempt_number, response,
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 316, in **call**
checker_response = checker(attempt_number, response,
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 222, in **call**
return self._check_caught_exception(
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
raise caught_exception
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
http_response = self._send(request)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
return self.http_session.send(request)
File "C:\Users\kbollu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 281, in send
raise SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://cloudtrail.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

GETTING THIS ERROR WHILE TRYING TO USE A METHOD 'lookup_events' FROM boto3 cloudtrail client.